# Should there be any problem cooling Mysore Pak outside a refrigerator?

Tags: baking, food-safety, indian-cuisine, vegan

I am interested to make Mysore Pak, the Indian sub-continent lightly-roasted Besan (Chickpea flour) based cake.

I can indeed lightly-roast one cup of Besan, add one cup of sugar directly together with one cup of water, stir all three ingredients to a fine smooth batter and and then add about one cup of coconut and/or sunflower oil and mix well a few minutes to get an extremely unified batter (with no "lumps" or "chunks").

My problem is with cooling off the batter until solidification (which is how the batter is made into a cake):
The refrigerator in the apartment I rent is a bit small for the pan in the sense that even if it is well situated it will probably touch plastic surface, walls and dishes and that I want to avoid.

**Should there be any problem cooling Mysore Pak outside a refrigerator?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batters are not shelf stable. It doesn't matter if their ingredients are shelf stable by themselves or not. So you have to follow the [basic food safety rules](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/how-do-i-know-if-food-left-at-room-temperature-is-still-safe-to-eat) for non-shelf-stable food. In particular, you have to ensure (no matter by what means) that it doesn't spend more than 4 hours with an internal temperature between 4 and 60 degrees Celsius.

If you can prove that your cooling procedure does that, you are fine. If you don't know, then it is unsafe.

Comment: Mysore pak is shelf-stable; it's something like a semi-hard fudge. It's about 2:2:3 gram-flour:fat:sugar by the end of preparation - no water will remain. It is not normally refrigerated and keeps well in an airtight container at ambient temperature for weeks (of course it's way too good to actually last that long though!)

Comment: @Zanna this doesn't sound shelf-stable to me - I have had 3-2-1 pie crust get spoiled in the fridge (admittedly made with butter, maybe the batter you talk about is made with ghee). Anyway, 1) nominally, somebody has to test a food/ingredient before it can be declared shelf stable, and 2) the OP calls it a "batter", and describes quite a high water content in the quesiton body.

Comment: well I think both "batter" and "cake" are misleading here... Mysore pak is a candy, not a cake. I guess I should write an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that Mysore pak is a candy, not a cake.

There is no stage in the preparation of Mysore pak that requires a refrigerator. You may prefer to store it in the refrigerator once made.

Your description of the method doesn't sound right. Although water will be used in making Mysore pak, it is only used to dissolve the sugar so that it does not burn when heated. The sugar syrup will be heated to single thread consistency (230-235 degrees Celsius) so all the water will have boiled off by that stage. When the sugar reaches single thread consistency, then you add the besan that you have previously roasted in oil, whisk the mixture to a smooth consistency, and then you add the very hot ghee or oil little by little, stirring all the time. If the sugar is not hot enough at the stage when you add the besan, the Mysore pak will not set properly.

After you finish adding the oil and combining well, you let the mixture start bubbling and then immediately pour it out onto a prepared greased plate or greaseproof paper. Of course, it will be very hot. It will have a thick consistency and it will quickly start to become hard. It is easiest to cut it into pieces while it is still warm, after 5-10 minutes. When it reaches the ambient temperature, it will be completely set and have a crunchy, chewy, crumbly fudge consistency. The cooling stage is complete.

Of course, one should not put hot food directly into the refrigerator, so following the correct procedure for making Mysore pak, which involves cooling from a very high temperature to ambient temperature, would not require a refrigerator.

After cooling and cutting, You can transfer your finished candy to a smaller container that you can conveniently put in your small fridge, which may prolong its shelf life. But Mysore pak is not sold as a chilled item and as far as I know people often keep it at ambient temperature in an airtight container.

Comment: +1 for the perfect recipe. Including the string consistency of sugar. I make mysore pak with this method only. Though I roast besan before without oil.

Comment: @Ojasvi I will try it that way - maybe it will be easier to mix :)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you end your recipe with the correct consistency, no need to keep it in the refrigerator. Always good to keep at room temperature for 6 to 8 hours in order to get a perfect color gradient starting from light yellow to dark at the center. Original Mysore Pak is a little hard compare to Ghee Mysore Pak.